# Workaround needed, PHP dechex maximum integer

Tags: php, hex, largenumber

I need to convert some large integers to hex but I am only getting partial results due to the dechex maximum integer limitation.

eg 1:

```
echo dechex(319259235818);
```

**returns: 555555ea** when it should be returning **4A555555EA**

eg 2:

```
echo dechex(51539607576);
```

**returns: 18** when it should be returning **C00000018**

anyone knows of a way to get around this limitation?

Comment: Are you running on 32-bit or 64-bit PHP?

Comment: Try using [bcmath](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.bc.php#99130)

Comment: The maximum integer size is a core PHP limitation, not a dechex() one. You'll have to find a way to do it with strings. @OneTrickPony's comment suggests a method.

Comment: @MarkBaker seems my dev environment is 32bit, tried the script on 64bit server and I am getting correct results. thanks for the quick help